# Swift 2D Array optional Type and subscripting (Beta 3)

Tags: swift

I have a 2D array that worked in Beta 2.  However, in Beta 3 I'm getting '@lvalue $T15 is not identical to T?' when setting via subscript.

```
class Array2D<T> {
let columns: Int
let rows: Int
let array: [T?] 

init(columns: Int, rows: Int) {
    self.columns = columns
    self.rows = rows
    array = [T?](count: rows*columns, repeatedValue: nil)
}

subscript(column: Int, row: Int) -> T? {
    get {
        return array[row*columns + column]
    }
    set {
        array[row*columns + column] = newValue  // Error here
    }
}}
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Beta3 constant arrays are completely immutable while variable arrays are entirely mutable. Change `let array: [T?]` to `var array: [T?]` and your code should work.